# generated sources of other modules

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a multi-module maven project. I use maven build helper plugin to automatically add generated sources to the classpath.

I am able to use the generated sources of module-X in module-X, however, when I add module-X as a dependency to module-Y, the generated sources of module-X are not visible because they are not included in the X.jar file.

Is there a way to include the generated sources in the jar file or force maven to generate sources of dependencies?

Comment: do you use the source plugin? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/

Comment: Adding the generated source to the classpath via build-helper does not make sense. I suppose you have a module which generates code ? The generated source files should never being part of the jar file. For such purposes a file called `xyz-VERSION-sources.jar` exists but it does not belong on the classpath. Using a module which generates sources is to define a simple dependency to the appropriate module...furthermore it would really help to see your pom files...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your explanation. Obviously, something with my approach is wrong. I am using maven-processor-plugin which has the JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor that generates sources under the `generated-sources` folder of a maven module. The problem is, I extend the BaseEntityModel in another maven module which results in generating: public class UserEntity_ extends BaseEntityModel_ { ... }. This gives compilation error because it cannot find BaseEntityModel_ class (it is in another maven module). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You have to add a dependency to the module which generates the code? Have you done so?

Comment: Yes, of course, @khmarbaise. Since the generated sources are not part of the jar, I still got compilation error

Comment: It is not related to the generated source code. The module if correctly configured compile also the generated java code into class file which will result in a usual jar file which can be used as a dependency and in that case it has to be used as one...please make an example project cause it sounds like there is a misunderstanding of the concept..

Comment: Strangely, the generated static metamodel sources are not part of jar @khmarbaise. But, I added some specifications classes that use those generated static metamodel classes and now they are in the jar, I don't know how! Problem is not solved but bypassed for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify that the generated classes should be part of the output jar file:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>generatedClassesFolderPath</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Replace the `generatedClassesFolderPath` with the relative path of the folder where the generated classes are.

More info:

- [How to include/exclude content from jar artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and I solve it as follows:

Add an application class under package such as `src/main/java/com.....` in your `module-X` and add a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. In addition to this, the application class can be no content.
[image: like this]

Make sure `module-X` in `module-Y` dependencies and restart `module-Y.